# Whats wrong with this boolean method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, return, equals

Hi I have this method which I created. Its job is to receive an Integer A, which can either be 10 or 30. It is meant to return TRUE if the value is ten, and false otherwise.

```
public static boolean checkStatus(int a){
        if(a.equals(10)){
              return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
```

For some reason I am getting a compilation error in the if(a.equals(10)) condition, which says INT CANNOT BE DEREFERNCED. If I'm not mistaken, isn't the .equals() method the way to go in this circumstance?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the compilation error tell you?

Comment: if(a.equals(10)) is a string comparision. not for integers. please follow a==10 in your if condition

Comment: @NarendraPal No, it is not a string comparison, it's just an illegal method call.  Even if `s` is a `String`, `s.equals(10)` is not a string comparison,; it always returns `false` without comparing anything.  `equals` is a method that can apply to any object, not just strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitives in Java (`int`, `long`, `float`, etc..) don't have member methods, so the call

```
if (a.equals(10))
```

will not compile, as you're trying to de-reference a primitive. Instead, you want to use the `==` operator to compare primitive values:

```
if (a == 10)
```

and reserve the use of the `equals()` method for non-primitive `Objects`

Comment: Could you explain when the .equals() method would be appropriate. I keep forgetting this one :( Thanks!

Comment: @user3029345 You only should use .equals() when comparing Objects.

Comment: @user3029345 I added a note to the bottom of the answer. In short, the equals method belongs to the `Object` cosmic superclass, and therefore all other classes in Java, since they must extend `Object` in their hierarchy chain, inherit some version of `equals`. All objects should be compared using this method, as comparing objects with `==` will only compare the references of the objects to see if the reference is pointing to the same place in memory (not exactly, but close enough).

Comment: @user3029345 `equals()` should always be used instead of `==` for `String`, `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, and some other Java-defined classes.  For other objects, `equals()` is appropriate **if** it makes sense for two different instances of a class to be "equal" somehow.  It doesn't always make sense--what would it mean for two `JComponent`s to be equal?  When it does make sense, the class needs to define an `equals` method (and `hashCode`).  Sometimes you still want to test whether two references refer to the same object; then use `==`.  Use `==` when comparing for `null`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `equals` for *objects* but an `int` is a *primitive* type <sup>(a)</sup>, rather than an object.

Hence you need something like:

```
public static boolean checkStatus (int a) {
    if (a == 10)
        return true;
   return false;
}
```

or the shorter and more sensible (in this case):

```
public static boolean checkStatus (int a) {
    return (a == 10);
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The purists will argue this is proof that Java is not really an object-oriented language, but that's because they're raving loonies :-)

Comment: +1 for the shorthand (a == 10). Redundant if statements are useless.

Comment: Just curious, is there no autoboxing for OPs case?

Comment: where is the wrapper to box it?

Comment: @AntonH, autoboxing happens (for example) when you pass an `int` to a function expecting an `Integer`, or when you assign an `int` to an `Integer` variable. The OP's original `if` statement is neither of those. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html for more detail.

Comment: @paxdiablo Okay, thanks for the info. I thought it was all the time, but you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public static boolean checkStatus(int a){
        if(a==10){
              return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
```

or

```
public static boolean checkStatus(Integer a){

        if(a.equals(new Integer(10))){
              return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I'd create a whole new object in that second case when you could just do `if (a.intValue() == 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

`equals()` method belongs to `Object` class of `Java` and it has to `override` each and every Object classes like `String, Integer and MyObject(implemented class)`. But `int` is not a `Java Object` and there is no `equals()` method there.

you can just use `==` with int values and you can simplify your code as bellow.

```
public static boolean checkStatus(int a){
    return a==10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`equals` is used for non-primitives basically for Objects.

`==` is used for primitives.

So, you can use it

```
public static boolean checkStatus (int a) {
    if (a == 10)
        return true;
   return false;
}
```

**Example 1:**
For object, if equals method are overridden, then "equals" method will return true.

```
public class Employee {
    int id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee e = (Employee) obj;
        return id == e.id;
    }

    Employee(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(5);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(5);
        System.out.println("e1.equals(e2) is: " + e1.equals(e2));
        System.out.println("(e1 == e2) is: " + (e1 == e2));
    }
}
```

Output:

> e1.equals(e2) is: **true**
>
> (e1 == e2) is:  **false**

**Example 2:**
For object, if equals method are not overridden, then "equals" method works as "=="

```
public class Employee {
    int id;

    Employee(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(5);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(5);
        System.out.println("e1.equals(e2) is: " + e1.equals(e2));
        System.out.println("(e1 == e2) is: " + (e1 == e2));
    }
}
```

Output:

> e1.equals(e2) is: **false**
>
> (e1 == e2) is: **false**

Here "equals" method works as "==". So, don't forget to override the equals method for object.

Answer (score 0):

**int** is a primitive in Java and primitives does not have behaviours a.k.a methods.

hence you cannot call `.equals` on `int`. So the options here are to use a `==`

```
public static boolean checkStatus(Integer a){
  return (a==10);
}
```

or convert the `int` to [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) which is a wrapper class

```
public static boolean checkStatus(Integer a){
    return a.equals(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with Integer Class

```
  Integer x = 5;
  Integer y = 10;
  Integer z =5;
  Short a = 5;

  System.out.println(x.equals(y));  
  System.out.println(x.equals(z)); 
  System.out.println(x.equals(a));
```

Output:

```
  false
  true
  false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course wrap the integer up as :

```
Integer i = new Integer(a);
```

Then the equals function can be used with 'i', the new Integer object.